# Bootstrap navbar will not function as a sticky navbar, how do i make it work

Tags: html

I can't get the navbar to function as a sticky navbar for this class project.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>fish</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <img>
        <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">CLOSING COSTS <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            REALTOR RESOURCES
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Live Transactional Support</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Title Talk</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tutorials</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Blog</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button" aria-pressed="true">SUBMIT CONTRACT</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg active" role="button" aria-pressed="true">SIGN IN</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div>

        </div>
        <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae provident cumque distinctio, nulla beatae deserunt iusto saepe quae. Quas fugiat vero voluptatem, fuga, nostrum quibusdam labore ipsam voluptates dolores velit.   
        </p>
        <div>
  <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias consectetur consequatur veritatis accusamus blanditiis labore aspernatur quam! Repellendus delectus sint dolorem maxime natus, rem dolorum similique consectetur deserunt facilis explicabo.    
        </p>
        </div>
        <div>
  <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, ut, assumenda? Molestiae quidem eum ratione provident consequatur non quibusdam nesciunt nam aperiam numquam suscipit error optio, minus, doloribus quaerat exercitationem!    
        </p>
        </div>
        <div>
  <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta quaerat velit a adipisci id, sunt harum asperiores sit beatae pariatur rerum voluptatem ducimus libero ex. Tenetur voluptatum molestiae, possimus atque!   
        </p>
        </div>
        <div>
  <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus commodi voluptatibus omnis adipisci, minus neque cum nesciunt itaque voluptate deserunt harum? Aliquam totam nemo, a explicabo tenetur, repudiandae vero voluptatem! 
        </p>
        </div>
        <div>
  <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero perspiciatis laboriosam impedit, aliquid at temporibus aperiam voluptatum earum. Veniam natus quibusdam illo excepturi totam aliquam ratione ex fugiat, molestiae ipsam.  
        </p>
        </div>
        <div>
  <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem eveniet sed minus. Veniam voluptatum aut, reprehenderit exercitationem sequi nesciunt, error, ex aliquid numquam saepe hic asperiores quam dolorem, aspernatur inventore?   
        </p>
        </div>
        <div>
  <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, necessitatibus sunt eius placeat, suscipit velit cumque distinctio eum quibusdam qui libero eos optio labore dolor beatae illum ipsa fugiat ratione. 
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, necessitatibus sunt eius placeat, suscipit velit cumque distinctio eum quibusdam qui libero eos optio labore dolor beatae illum ipsa fugiat ratione. 
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, necessitatibus sunt eius placeat, suscipit velit cumque distinctio eum quibusdam qui libero eos optio labore dolor beatae illum ipsa fugiat ratione. 
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, necessitatibus sunt eius placeat, suscipit velit cumque distinctio eum quibusdam qui libero eos optio labore dolor beatae illum ipsa fugiat ratione. 
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, necessitatibus sunt eius placeat, suscipit velit cumque distinctio eum quibusdam qui libero eos optio labore dolor beatae illum ipsa fugiat ratione. 
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, necessitatibus sunt eius placeat, suscipit velit cumque distinctio eum quibusdam qui libero eos optio labore dolor beatae illum ipsa fugiat ratione. 
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, necessitatibus sunt eius placeat, suscipit velit cumque distinctio eum quibusdam qui libero eos optio labore dolor beatae illum ipsa fugiat ratione. 
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, necessitatibus sunt eius placeat, suscipit velit cumque distinctio eum quibusdam qui libero eos optio labore dolor beatae illum ipsa fugiat ratione. 
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, necessitatibus sunt eius placeat, suscipit velit cumque distinctio eum quibusdam qui libero eos optio labore dolor beatae illum ipsa fugiat ratione. 
                              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, necessitatibus sunt eius placeat, suscipit velit cumque distinctio eum quibusdam qui libero eos optio labore dolor beatae illum ipsa fugiat ratione. 
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, necessitatibus sunt eius placeat, suscipit velit cumque distinctio eum quibusdam qui libero eos optio labore dolor beatae illum ipsa fugiat ratione. 
                                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, necessitatibus sunt eius placeat, suscipit velit cumque distinctio eum quibusdam qui libero eos optio labore dolor beatae illum ipsa fugiat ratione. 

        </p>
        </div>
    </main>

</body>
<footer>

</footer>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use fixed-top

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>fish</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <img>
        <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">CLOSING COSTS <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            REALTOR RESOURCES
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Live Transactional Support</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Title Talk</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tutorials</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Blog</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTACT</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button" aria-pressed="true">SUBMIT CONTRACT</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg active" role="button" aria-pressed="true">SIGN IN</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div>

        </div>
        <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae provident cumque distinctio, nulla beatae deserunt iusto saepe quae. Quas fugiat vero voluptatem, fuga, nostrum quibusdam labore ipsam voluptates dolores velit.   
        </p>
        <div>
  <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias consectetur consequatur veritatis accusamus blanditiis labore aspernatur quam! Repellendus delectus sint dolorem maxime natus, rem dolorum similique consectetur deserunt facilis explicabo.    
        </p>
        </div>
        <div>
  <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, ut, assumenda? Molestiae quidem eum ratione provident consequatur non quibusdam nesciunt nam aperiam numquam suscipit error optio, minus, doloribus quaerat exercitationem!    
        </p>
        </div>
        <div>
  <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta quaerat velit a adipisci id, sunt harum asperiores sit beatae pariatur rerum voluptatem ducimus libero ex. Tenetur voluptatum molestiae, possimus atque!   
        </p>
        </div>
        <div>
  <p>
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus commodi voluptatibus omnis adipisci, minus neque cum nesciunt itaque voluptate deserunt harum? Aliquam totam nemo, a explicabo tenetur, repudiandae vero voluptatem! 
        </p>
        </div>
        <div>
  <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero perspiciatis laboriosam impedit, aliquid at temporibus aperiam voluptatum earum. Veniam natus quibusdam illo excepturi totam aliquam ratione ex fugiat, molestiae ipsam.  
        </p>
        </div>
        <div>
  <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatem eveniet sed minus. Veniam voluptatum aut, reprehenderit exercitationem sequi nesciunt, error, ex aliquid numquam saepe hic asperiores quam dolorem, aspernatur inventore?   
        </p>
        </div>
        <div>
  <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, necessitatibus sunt eius placeat, suscipit velit cumque distinctio eum quibusdam qui libero eos optio labore dolor beatae illum ipsa fugiat ratione. 
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, necessitatibus sunt eius placeat, suscipit velit cumque distinctio eum quibusdam qui libero eos optio labore dolor beatae illum ipsa fugiat ratione. 
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, necessitatibus sunt eius placeat, suscipit velit cumque distinctio eum quibusdam qui libero eos optio labore dolor beatae illum ipsa fugiat ratione. 
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, necessitatibus sunt eius placeat, suscipit velit cumque distinctio eum quibusdam qui libero eos optio labore dolor beatae illum ipsa fugiat ratione. 
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, necessitatibus sunt eius placeat, suscipit velit cumque distinctio eum quibusdam qui libero eos optio labore dolor beatae illum ipsa fugiat ratione. 
                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, necessitatibus sunt eius placeat, suscipit velit cumque distinctio eum quibusdam qui libero eos optio labore dolor beatae illum ipsa fugiat ratione. 
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, necessitatibus sunt eius placeat, suscipit velit cumque distinctio eum quibusdam qui libero eos optio labore dolor beatae illum ipsa fugiat ratione. 
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, necessitatibus sunt eius placeat, suscipit velit cumque distinctio eum quibusdam qui libero eos optio labore dolor beatae illum ipsa fugiat ratione. 
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, necessitatibus sunt eius placeat, suscipit velit cumque distinctio eum quibusdam qui libero eos optio labore dolor beatae illum ipsa fugiat ratione. 
                              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, necessitatibus sunt eius placeat, suscipit velit cumque distinctio eum quibusdam qui libero eos optio labore dolor beatae illum ipsa fugiat ratione. 
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, necessitatibus sunt eius placeat, suscipit velit cumque distinctio eum quibusdam qui libero eos optio labore dolor beatae illum ipsa fugiat ratione. 
                                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum, necessitatibus sunt eius placeat, suscipit velit cumque distinctio eum quibusdam qui libero eos optio labore dolor beatae illum ipsa fugiat ratione. 

        </p>
        </div>
    </main>

</body>
<footer>

</footer>

</html>
```

You can also look into it https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_navbar_sticky